# custom script to log in as a regular user on local machine but remotely ssh as root

Tags: ssh

Good day all, i am not sure if this is the right question to ask. I am a newbie . Pls do anyone have an idea of a possible custom bash script that can be use to login over ssh into a remote server but will automatically sudo to root on the remote server without having to input a password. i am task to find a way to run same operation over multiple servers but i can not log in as root by default

## command will be of the form below where script.sh will be some sort of ssh wrapper script. i have looked at possible ssh documentation but no luck.

user1@localmachine~:script.sh server_name

## root@remotemachine~#:

Addition: to be more specific, how can i bypass the two password prompt by running command ssh -t $SERVER "sudo su"

i can observe i got prompted the first time to authenticate to $SERVER and the second password prompt to authenticate the "sudo su"

i will like to play around any suggestion provided in my personal lab to weigh in on the potential risk

Comment: That would make a nice security hole ...

Comment: Agreed, the security implications of the approach are huge, and to provide an answer is a bad idea.  Instead, @sammie, please consider a tool appropriate to the task, such as `ansible`.  The time invested in learning it will payoff in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the support. am starting to look into Ansible to achieve samething